# Cube not running the update from DTSX

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, sql-server-2017

I create a DTSX package to update data in a database and then to run the DIMENSIONS and CUBE. If I run the cube directly in Visual Studio or if I process manually the dimensions and the cube, everything works correctly.

The problem is when I create a job in SQL Server Agent to run the DTSX. The job finish without problem, the data is updated in the database but the cube and dimensions aren't updated.

[image]
How can I debbug the process? the log file:

> Utilidad de ejecuci¢n de paquetes de Microsoft (R) SQL Server Version
>   14.0.1000.169 for 64-bit Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. Todos los derechos reservados.
>
> Iniciado: 12:38:13 DTExec: la ejecuci¢n del paquete devolvi¢
>   **DTSER_SUCCESS (0)**. Iniciado: 12:38:13 Finalizado: 12:39:56
>   Transcurrido:  102.61 segundos

Comment: Can you translate the error for us?

Comment: there is no error. It is a "success" code...

Comment: First check the ssis logs. Don't make any assumptions until you've checked them.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Did you check the logs? Did those two steps start?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid when I process the cube from SSIS or Visual Studio (DTSX) there is no problem, all works fine. The problem is when I excecute the task in the SQL Server Agent, there is no error, and the cube is not processed. So now I'm looking to configure SSIS logs, because i couldn't fin any error in the process.

Comment: Yes. Configure logs and confirm the steps were run. At this point we don’t know they were run.

Comment: @nick.McDermaid so here we are. I configure the logs for SSIS to a file and to Windows event log. If I execute the package directly from Visual Studio (DTSX) the proces finish correctly, the data is updated and the cube it's okey (and the log is writen). If I excecute the SQL Server Agent task, the data is updated but the cube is not updated and i don't see anithing in the log. So I think it can be a problem of windows user's permissions.

Comment: What you’re looking for is an indication that those steps ran. If you see “nothing” then there’s no proof they ran.